# Can I spontaneously give a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I am getting first-rate help on something that bugs me but was not originally staked in my question for a bounty.

How can I give a bounty spontaneously to a contributor for his/her answer (after the fact) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same you would any other bounty.

1. Hit "Start a Bounty"
2. Add the bounty with the reason "one of the answers is exemplary" or what ever it is now.
3. After the time period for having to 'wait' to deliver the bounty, award the bounty to the answer you think deserves it.

I've done this myself, and I"ve also received such myself, in the past, so it should work.